# Creating a new 2D array from regular array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

If I have an JavaScript array:

```
a = ["12", "34", "56", "78"];
```

and I want to make a new 2D array like this:

```
b = [ ["12345678"], ["34567812"], ["56781234"], ["78123456"] ];
```

I know this should be pretty simple but I just can't figure it out... My brain is kinda slow today... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join the string at various pivot locations.

```
n = [];
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    n.push(a.slice(i).join("") + a.slice(0,i).join(""));
}
```

This outputs:

```
[ "12345678", "34567812", "56781234", "78123456" ]
```

I am not certain whether having nested single element arrays in the output was a mistake, but if that is required just add square brackets inside `push`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` in conjunction with `concat` like this:

```
var newA = a.map(function() {
    var copy = a.slice();
    return [copy.concat(copy.splice(0, arguments[1])).join('')];
});

// => [ ["12345678"], ["34567812"], ["56781234"], ["78123456"] ];
```